# Start tmux with specific layout

Tags: tmux

I have a question and searched on the web but didn't find a specific solution, or solutions didn't work for me.
In order to start tmux with a specific layout of panes, I'd like to setup my `tmux.conf` accordingly.

Now, I found something like this:

```
new -s my_sess # create new session

neww -n shell # create new window

splitw -v
```

Which has no effect, since I see only one window, not split into panes. Another trial was like this:

```
# Automatically set window title
set-window-option -g automatic-rename on
set-option -g set-titles on

# Split the pane horizontally
splitw -h
```

Which results in an error `no current target`.

It's probably a stupid mistake of mine caused by poor understanding. But I hope that people here might be able to help.

Answer (score 6):

I'd say that this very basic task is covered abominably in the available tmux resources.

It cost me **six hours** of perusing material to come to a solution. The biggest help came from https://gist.github.com/sdondley/b01cc5bb1169c8c83401e438a652b84e

Your minimal .tmux.conf file shall be (you got there 99%):

```
new -s my_sess # create new session
neww -n shell # create new window
split-window -t shell # split vertically the window just created
```

and you have to launch it with `tmux attach` instead of a plain `tmux`.

I have created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/Muzietto/325344c2b1b3b723985a85800cafef4f) to sum up my experiences. It covers also topics like launching different commands in each new pane.

Answer (score 0):

If you create new sessions in .tmux.conf, you probably want to start tmux with `tmux attach` not `tmux new`. If you don't, you will be creating both your session in .tmux.conf *and* a new session, which is probably not what you want. Your first attempt looks OK, so I guess this is what you are doing.

Also remember .tmux.conf is only loaded on server startup, so only the first time you run tmux. If you want to create a new session like this later, put it in a separate config file and load it with `source-file`.